# Moment.js cannot parse string to date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i have a string in javascript. The string is in this format: `14. November 2018`

Now I want to create a Javascript date object. I tried this with moment.js

```
moment('14. November 2018').format('DD. MMM YYYY');
```

The browser shows this error:

```
Invalid date
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reading the docs again. The right way is:

```
moment('14. November 2018', 'DD. MMMM YYYY');
```

Comment: Close, but you should use `MMMM` if you have the full name of the month.  `MMM` is the abbreviation form.  It may still work for parsing, but will give different output for formatting later.   Also, how will you be passing single digit days? If it will be like `'01. November 2018'`, then continue to use `DD`.  But if instead it would be like `'1. November 2018'` then you should just use `D`.  It will still parse both single and two digit days, but will omit the leading zero if used for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
moment(str, 'DD. MMMM YYYY').toDate();
```

Comment: Please add a little detail of how you think this will help the OP